# Sublime text overrides Emmet snippets

Tags: html, sublimetext3, code-snippets, overriding, emmet

My problem is simply that some of the ***Emmet snippets and abbreviations get overridden*** by the Sublime Text 3 default tags - for example, when I type 'link' and press TAB I *don't* end up with:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="">`

as stated in the Emmet documentation (https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/master/lib/snippets.json).

Instead I get:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">`

This which is the Sublime Text 3 default. The same goes for 'img' and a few other useful tags, and now I'm wondering: why is that and what can I do "fix" it? ***I want the Emmet snippets to have "first dibs", and not the other way around.***

Answer (score 1):

Open **`Preferences -> Package Settings -> Emmet -> Settings-User`** and add the following content (it should be empty upon opening it for the first time):

```json
{
    "remove_html_completions": true
}
```

Save the file, then restart Sublime.

For a look at all the options you can customize, open **`Preferences -> Package Settings -> Emmet -> Settings-Default`**. If you see anything that you'd like to change, copy the setting to `Settings-User`, making sure there's a comma `,` at the end of each line except the last one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately this does not seem to work :(. I'm actually aware of the custom settings file and I've been tinkering with it quite a bit - changing settings and writing custom Emmet snippets. Just for debugging purposes, this is what it looks like now:

{

"remove_html_completions": true

}

But it still won't work. Does it really work for you?

Comment: Through further investigation I've found that it works if you set "auto_complete" to false in the Sublime Text 3 settings. Problem is though that I would really like to have auto complete enabled :(

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record I want to convey that I've finally found the solution to my problem. It would seem as if Emmet has this built in setting where you can specify in which scopes you want your code editors' defaults to override Emmet, and as a default this is set to "text.html". Hence what I needed to do to resolve my issue was just to change this setting to none by simply typing

```
{

"disabled_single_snippet_for_scopes": ""

}
```

In the Emmet user settings. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It’s pretty hard for Emmet to play nice with native Sublime Text snippets due to lack of API. But Emmet tries to guess what you want to do as much as possible.

By default, when you type something in ST that matches native snippet you’ll likely see an autocomplete popup with snippets proposals. Which means you’ll likely want to expand native snippet by pressing Tab key. On the other hand, most Emmet abbreviations doesn’t look like predefined snippet, e.g. you won’t see autocomplete popup when typing abbreviation.

Thus, *Emmet doesn’t expand abbreviations by Tab key when autocomplete popup is visible*. It seems like a decent solution for native snippets problem (ST API can tell if popup is visible). I’m pretty sure in your `link` example there was autocomplete popup visible.

For hardcore Emmet users it’s possible to disable this behaviour and force Emmet to always expand abbreviations by Tab, event if autocomplete popup is visible. To do so, go to **Preferences → Settings-User** and add the following option:

```
"disable_tab_abbreviations_on_auto_complete": false
```

See https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/blob/master/Preferences.sublime-settings#L29